# Countable connected spaces

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers, connectedness

I can not think of any countable connected subsets in $\mathbb{R}$ (with subspace topology)..

Are there any such?

Only countable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ that i am familiar with is $\mathbb{Q}$ which is not connected $\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{N}$  which are not connected..

Please help me to understand this better..

EDIT : First of all excuse me for what i am going to write next.

As it turned out that what i am thinking about connected countable sets is trivially true, I have two options now.. One is to delete this question Second is to generalize this question..

I choose to do the next..

I would like to know more about non trivial connected countable spaces non necessarily as euclidean setting...

Comment: Thm: A countable $T_3$ space is disconnected. And metric spaces and their subspaces are $T_3$. There are however countable Hausdorff spaces that are connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $\mathbb R$, connectedness is equivalent to path connectedness. (I was wrong about the first claim - OPEN connected $\implies$ path connected.)

So if you had  connected subspace with more than one point, it would contain the image of $[0,1]$, and thus be uncountable.

As for your update, take something like $\mathbb Q$ and give it the trivial topology. Now it must be connected. You do not need reference to any one standard topology or construct any weird space. If you're asking for a non-trivial topology on some countable space which makes it connected, I'll think for a bit and get back to you... I don't think it's much harder.

Okay. Had to go check my notebook but I have seen such an example. It is an unusual topology on a familiar space.

The example goes like this. The space consists of the rational points of the plane on or above the $x$-axis. If (a,b) is such a point, with $\epsilon > 0$, then take the set $(a,b) + \{(r,0) \}$ either $|r-(a+b/\sqrt{3}|<\epsilon$ or $|r-(a-b/\sqrt{3})|<\epsilon$ to be a neighborhood. This is space is connectd because for each pair of neighborhoods, there is a point that they share in the closures. This space is also Hausdorff, which is pretty neat.

This isn't something I invented, I picked it up in a class... I wrote down that it was a result from someone named Bing. You could try googling this person to see more.

Come to think of it, I think you could take any countable set, and add a single point, and topologize it by saying that the open sets must contain the added point. This should be connected, but lacks the extra feature of being Hausdorff.

Comment: So, what ever i was thinking is correct.. There are no non trivial connected countable subsets...

Comment: That's exactly right. If you're not familiar with the fact I used, you should try to prove it. It is not particularly difficult. Also, this argument is slightly more general than your original question - it applies to all Euclidean spaces, not just $\mathbb R$

Comment: I could recall the result that you have used.. Thanks..

Comment: Excuse me.. I have changed the question little bit as the previous question is a very trivial one.. Please see if you can answer the edited question...

Comment: @cello The problem is still simple. You can just take any countable space and give it the trivial topology.

Comment: As i have told i am looking for non trivial examples

Comment: Okay. I have an example. I'll edit it in momentarily.

Comment: @AlfredYerger It is not true that connectedness and path-connectedness are equivalent in Euclidean space! See for instance the [topologist's sine curve](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topologist%27s_sine_curve).

Comment: Are you saying there are not so complicated non trivial examples? Can you give some reference so that i can look at it myself

Comment: @MarcPaul : Yes.. That is true.. Open connected is path connected..

Comment: Ah yeah. Local path-connectedness is needed.. which is true in $\mathbb R$ but not in the plane... I'll edit.

Answer (score 1):

There are four kinds of connected subspaces in $\Bbb R$:

- Empty set, if you consider it connected.
- Singletons, that is, sets with only one point.
- Intervals, that are not countable.
- $\Bbb R$, that is not countable.

Comment: @cello: He has listed the only connected sets in $\mathbb R$. He has indicated which ones are countable and which are not. How do you not see that this answers your question?

Comment: I was looking for non trivial ones.. I should have written that in my question that i am familiar with these.. Apologies..

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be a countable subset of $\Bbb R$ with at least two elements. Then $A$ is not connected. Indeed, if $a,b\in A$ with $a<b$ then $(a,b)\setminus A$ must be non-empty. If $c\in(a,b)\setminus A$ then $(-\infty,c) $ and $(c,\infty)$ are two disjoint open sets that cover $A$ and each has nontrivial intersection with $a$; hence $A$ is not connected.

Countable subsets of $\Bbb R$ with less than two elements *are* connected, though.

Comment: So, there are no non trivial connected subsets in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Excuse me.. I have changed the question little bit as the previous question is a very trivial one.. Please see if you can answer the edited question...